# Testing with Firesbase in Android Studio JUnit Test

Tags: java, android, firebase, junit

Firebase totally works fine in my Android Studio, but it crashes when I try to test it with it.

```
public class ExampleUnitTest {

    DatabaseReference rootReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference tournamentReference = rootReference.child("Tournaments");
    DatabaseReference matchReference = tournamentReference.child("Test Tournament").child("Matches");

    @Test
    public void addition_isCorrect() throws Exception {

        DatabaseReference testReference = matchReference.child("Nov 13, 2017 Team Eagles vs Team Tigers");

        testReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    assertEquals(snapshot.child("fieldName").getValue().toString(), "UIUC Sixpack Field");
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

In this test case, it gives me an error :

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Is there a way to solve make it work?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the json file does not exists in the right place. Redownload `google-services.json` file from Project Settings in the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) and put it in the right place in your project.

Comment: What do you mean by the "right place"? I think it's already in the right place.

Comment: The `google-services.json` file must be places in `app` directory of your project.

Comment: Try also this. Open firebase docs and check the Gradle Dependency Line under the Guide tab. Here you will see a list of service,Compare your service version of real-time database with the list. Make sure your firebase-database version in your build.gradle(Module: app) is same as in the Gradle dependency line.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?
Is there everything alright?